# Is it possible to provide a decendent class as a formal parameter in an overriden function and still compile

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

What is the best way to provide a mechanism in which a base class can have a function with a class parameter and a decendant class can override the function with a parameter that is a decendant of the base classes parameter. Confused, let me construct what I am would like to implement below:

**Base class**

```
public class BaseReportController
{
    private ActionResult InternalRenderReport(BaseReportModel model)
    {
        ReportExecution execution = this.GetReportExecution(model);
        execution.AddRequiredParameter("DatabaseName", aTargetDatabase);
        execution.AddRequiredParameter("DatabaseServerName", aTargetServer);
        //Send execution into ssrs wrappers to return a report payload
    }

    public virtual ReportExecution GetReportExecution(BaseReportModel model)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Extended class**

```
public class ExtendedReportController:BaseReportController
{
    public override ReportExecution GetReportExecution(ExtendedFromBaseReportModel model)
    {
        ReportExecution exec = new ReportExecution();
        exec.AddOptionalParameter("SomeID1", model.SomeID1);
        exec.AddOptionalParameter("SomeID2", model.SomeID2);
        return exec;
    }
}
```

Is there something like an anonymous parameter that would allow me to define `ExtendedFromBaseReportModel` as the formal parameter in the overridden method and still compile?

Comment: I am currently doing something similar, however, it amounts to copying and pasting a function in every derived class.

Comment: Oh I don't like that. I'd definitely be looking at interfaces.

Comment: I think I would run into the same issue with interfaces when I try to implement the interface using ExtendedFromBaseReportModel  instead of BaseReportModel. I think Kamil Pajdzik answered my question by hinting at typecasting. Hello programming 101. I think I overthought this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your base class and cast it to derived type inside your method.

```
public class ExtendedReportController:BaseReportController
{
    public override ReportExecution GetReportExecution(BaseReportModel model)
    {
        var castedModel = (ExtendedFromBaseReportModel) model;
        ReportExecution exec = new ReportExecution();
        exec.AddOptionalParameter("SomeID1", castedModel.SomeID1);
        exec.AddOptionalParameter("SomeID2", castedModel.SomeID2);
        return exec;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the Model coming over from the client is ExtendedFromBaseReportModel would that not cause a runtime error? And would I have all my extended metadata?

Comment: If `ExtendedFromBaseReportModel` derives from `BaseReportModel` then it won't cause runtime error. An instance of subclass is also an instance of baseclass.

Comment: doh! you are correct. I am thinking to much about it.

Comment: But what happens if model is actually `AnotherClassExtendedFromBaseReportModel`? Surely that *will* lead to a runtime error?

Comment: That's true. The easiest solution is to use `as` operator and check for null.